# Inherit decorators with multiple decorators

Tags: python, inheritance, python-decorators, mixins, metaclass

I have used the following Mixin class to inherit decorators along sub-classes. The Problem is that when a method has more than one decorator than they are not recognized (just the last one). For example, if I have the class:

```
class Example(InheritDecoratorsMixin): 
  
  @decorator1
  @decorator2
  def method(): 
    pass
```

Then any subclass would just inherit decorator1 but not decorator2 which I would like to have. Here is the Mixin class:

```
class InheritDecoratorsMixin:
  """Mixin Class that allows to inherit decorators.

  Each subclass of this class will have a '_decorator_registry'
  attribute which contains all decorators to be applied.

  Each decorator output must contain the attribute 'inherit_decorator'
  with itself as the value.
  """

  def __init_subclass__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init_subclass__(*args, **kwargs)
    decorator_registry = getattr(cls, '_decorator_registry', {}).copy()
    cls._decorator_registry = decorator_registry

    # Check for decorated objects in the mixin itself:
    for name, obj in __class__.__dict__.items():
      if (getattr(obj, 'inherit_decorator', False)
              and name not in decorator_registry):
        decorator_registry[name] = obj.inherit_decorator

    # annotate newly decorated methods in the current subclass:
    for name, obj in cls.__dict__.items():
      if (getattr(obj, 'inherit_decorator', False)
              and name not in decorator_registry):
        decorator_registry[name] = obj.inherit_decorator

    # finally, decorate all methods annotated in the registry:
    for name, decorator in decorator_registry.items():
      if (name in cls.__dict__ and getattr(
              getattr(cls, name), 'inherit_decorator', None) != decorator):
        setattr(cls, name, decorator(cls.__dict__[name]))
```

Thanks for any help.

For any decorator I would do:

```
def decorator(func): 
  def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

    ...
    
    return result

  wrapper.inherit_decorator = decorator
  return wrapper
```

Comment: I have added an exampled @DanGetz

Comment: It's not obvious what you are trying to do. You don't "inherit" decorators; the decorators are used to *define* `method`. It looks like you are trying to apply decorators to objects, but the decorators have *already been applied*. By the time `__init_subclass__` is called, `method` is the wrapper defined by `decorator2`, which "contains" the wrapper defined by `decorator1`, which "contains" the original function defined by the `def` statement.

Comment: What I basically want is that if I define a decorator for a method I want that decorator to be maintained in the subclass, so I have to somehow "inherit" the decorator as that is not provided by python itself. And with this metaclass I can handle this but just for one decorator per method. With chained decoratores this seems not to work.

Comment: @Patricio by "maintained", I guess you mean re-applied to a redefined method? Sounds like you want to keep a list of the chained decorators.

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is cumbersome, and if you are sure of this approach, just modify what you are doing accordingly:
your "decorator_registry"  as is in the code specifically ties one decorator per method name. Change your code so that each entry in the registry is a list, instead of a single object, and maintain that list, instead of just replacing decorators when finding new ones. Also, your decorators, instead of just marking the decorated function with the topmost decorator itself in the "inherit_decorator" method, should maintain a list of all underlying decorators in this attribute.

I have not tested this, as there should be plenty of corner cases,
but the general idea is:

```
from copy import copy
from functools import wraps

class InheritDecoratorsMixin:
  """Mixin Class that allows to inherit decorators.

  Each subclass of this class will have a '_decorator_registry'
  attribute which contains all decorators to be applied.

  Each decorator output must contain the attribute 'inherit_decorator'
  with itself as the value.
  """

  def __init_subclass__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init_subclass__(*args, **kwargs)
    decorator_registry = getattr(cls, '_decorator_registry', {}).copy()
    cls._decorator_registry = decorator_registry

    for class_obj in (__class__, cls):
        
        for name, obj in class_obj.__dict__.items():
            if getattr(obj, 'inherit_decorator', False):
                new_decorators = [deco for deco  in obj.inherit_decorator if deco.__name__ not in decorator_registry.get(name)]
                decorator_registry.setdefault(name, []).extend(new_decorators)

    # finally, decorate all methods annotated in the registry. 
    # note that this code might apply some decorators more than once.

    for name, decorators in decorator_registry.items():
        if name not in cls.__dict__: 
            continue
        method = getattr(cls, name)
        new_method = None
        for deco in decorators:
            if deco in getattr(method, inherit_decorators, []):
                continue
            new_method = deco(method)
        if new_method:
            setattr(cls, name, new_method)
            
def decorator(func): 
    @wraps(func)  # this call preserves name and other properties from the decorated function
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

        ...
        
        return result
    decorators = copy(getattr(func, "inherit_decorator", []))
    decorators.append(decorator)

    wrapper.inherit_decorator = decorators
    return wrapper
```